# file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1

Tags: php, ssl, https, openssl

I use PHP wamp with php_open_ssl.dll (version: OpenSSL 1.0.1d 5 Feb 2013).

When I tried to access https URL like this:

```
$result = file_get_contents($url, null, stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'protocol_version' => 1.1,
        'user_agent'       => 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0',
        'method'           => 'POST',
        'header'           => "Content-type: application/json\r\n".
                              "Connection: close\r\n" .
                              "Content-length: " . strlen($json_data) . "\r\n",
        'content'          => $json_data,
    ),
)));
```

I get the following warning:

```
file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1408F119:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac
```

Some say that this is caused because of bad version of SSL dll. Do you guys have any tips of how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance!